# Python tkinter custom Frame checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have several Checkboxes in an CustomFrame, but currently have the following missbehaviour:

If I click on a Checkbox, the whole column gets active and I want to have one the clicked one to be active. Is it possible to "reuse" Checkboxes in tk-derived classes and declare them in Subclasses?

[image: screenshot]

Mainwindow which uses SubFrames:

```
import tkinter as tk
import zmq
from time import sleep
import time
from threading import Thread

from glmPygameGlue import *
from networkRenderGlue import *
from quatLTI import *

import guiWidgets as gw


class Window(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)        
        #super().__init__()


        self.accWidget = gw.Widget_Vector(self, "ACC")
        self.gyroWidget = gw.Widget_Vector(self, "GYRO")
        self.magWidget = gw.Widget_Vector(self, "MAG")

        self.accWidget.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.gyroWidget.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.magWidget.grid(column=0, row=2) 

        self.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def AccBiasEnable(self):
        print("window accBiasEnable")

    def onClose(self):      
        exit()



    

root = tk.Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.onClose)

root.wm_title("Input-Gui Quaternion-HP")

root.geometry("500x500")
root.mainloop()
```

SubFrames:

```
import tkinter as tk


class TripleCheckboxVertical(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.xBias = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='bias', command=master.master.AccBiasEnable)    
        self.yBias = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='cos')        
        self.zBias = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='noise')
        
        self.xBias.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.yBias.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.zBias.grid(column=2, row=0)

    def callBackFunc(self, event=None):
        print("cb event!1")

class Widget_Vector(tk.LabelFrame):

    def __init__(self, master=None, text_=""):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, text=text_)    
        self.master = master         

        self.labelX = tk.Label(self, text="x")        
        self.labelY = tk.Label(self, text="y")        
        self.labelZ = tk.Label(self, text="z")

        self.cb3X = TripleCheckboxVertical(self)
        self.cb3Y = TripleCheckboxVertical(self)
        self.cb3Z = TripleCheckboxVertical(self)

        self.labelX.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.labelY.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.labelZ.grid(column=0, row=2)

        self.cb3X.grid(column=1,row=0)
        self.cb3Y.grid(column=1,row=1)
        self.cb3Z.grid(column=1,row=2)
```

Any ideas?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, add a variable to each checkbutton. I've created 3 `BooleanVar` which store the value of the checkbutton and makes them behave independently. I've also added a get method to return the value of each checkbox:

```
class TripleCheckboxVertical(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.xBiasVar = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.yBiasVar = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.zBiasVar = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.xBias = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='bias', variable = self.xBiasVar, command=master.master.AccBiasEnable)    
        self.yBias = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='cos', variable = self.yBiasVar)        
        self.zBias = tk.Checkbutton(self, text='noise', variable = self.zBiasVar)
        
        self.xBias.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.yBias.grid(column=1, row=0)
        self.zBias.grid(column=2, row=0)
    def get(self):
        return {"bias":self.xBiasVar.get(), "cos":self.yBiasVar.get(), "noise":self.zBiasVar.get()}
```

I also added a get method to `Widget_Vector`:

```
def get(self):
        return {"x":self.cb3X.get(), "y":self.cb3Y.get(), "z":self.cb3Z.get()}
```

If you wanted the value of x bias for GYRO, for example, you can do `self.gyroWidget.get()["x"]["bias"]`